# Simple quote in variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, single-quotes

I would like to accept simple quotes into a string without crashing my curl request.

here my curl request :

```
curl -XGET "localhost:9200/test/all/_search?pretty" -d \'{"query":"'+question+'"}\'';
```

If `question = 'It's OK'`.

I will have an error durong my request

```
 Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

For the moment I tried several solutions (like this one below), but none worked :

```
question = question.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
```

Have you got a solution to fix it ?

Comment: and can you post sample URLs which are failing ?

Comment: Sorry I just updated my question. Hope it's clearer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The following works OK, guess you just need to escape your backslashes

`let question = "lskdlskd'sldklskd"; 
 question = question.replace(/'/g, "\\\\'");`

Comment: It doesn't work, I have still the unterminated quoted string error. `'It's ok'` become ----> `'it\\'s ok'`